# Is there any other formula for this equation?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to get the total quantity of the item requested from 5 columns in google sheets so I used a formula but it gives me "Argument must be a range.". I also used another formula but it only counts the total number of the word "stretch film" itself. What formula should I use?

I want to get the total quantity of the item requested from 5 columns in google sheets so I used this formula "=SUMIFS($B10="","",COUNTIF(TransInfo!K1:T,"Stretch Film"))" but it gives me "Argument must be a range.". I also used this formula "=IF($B10="","",COUNTIF(TransInfo!K1:T,"Stretch Film"))" but it only counts the total number of the word "stretch film" itself. What formula should I use?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(L1:T; K1:S="Stretch Film"))
```